# ¿Cómo abrir un proyecto completo en Xcode?

Tags: php, javascript, html, xcode, macos

Tengo un proyecto que esta hecho en `html , js, php,` y todo esta en diferentes carpetas , la cuestión es que cuando quiero abrir la carpeta que contiene todo esto en Xcode , me sale esto:

> Could not open file.(/ruta/de/mi/proyecto).

Alguien tiene experiencia trabajando con Xcode que me diga si se puede trabajar un proyecto así en Xcode o no.

Gracias de antemano.